# Why is the performance in electron worse than in Chrome?

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I have an electron-reactjs app running on a Raspberry Pi (2 and 3 currently). It's a kind of a graphical dashboard.

If I access the dashboard on the RPI from my macbook everything runs smooth. But the performance on a monitor directly connected to the RPI is very poor. (e.g. changing opacity in 5 steps, which looks very laggy).

I don't think that the RPI is the major problem (Otherwise it would be also laggy when connectiong over the IP?), could be the chromium browser inside electron be the problem? I'm using Electron v24 so that shouldn't also be the problem. And if I run the Electron app on my macbook for developing purproses it's also not laggy.

So what slows the app on the directly connected monitor down? Is it the RPI? Then my question is: Why is the app smooth when connecting over the IP? Maybe someone knows the problem and solution for it.

Comment: Not electron developer but I am pretty sure "connecting over IP from your Macbook" would result in client side scripts being evaluated on the Macbook, as well as graphical rendering with hw acceleration which outperforms the PI in every aspect.

Comment: @qkhanhpro Oh true that makes sense sadly. A lot is client side rendered... Thanks, I didn't think of that.